# Visual Studio ClickOnce Web Deployment

Tags: web, web-deployment, clickonce

I would be most grateful if anyone could help me solve this problem with ClickOnce Web deployment.

I have read all the threads on this subject and I have also read through all the Microsoft documentation on the subject. They seem to say a lot without actually being direct or providing helpful examples. However, perhaps I am wrong and I have not looked in the right places.

I have already used ClickOnce successfully to deploy an application on the local area network.
It works well and really isn't that complicated. However, my goal is to deploy this application to customers, who are not connected to my local network.

I have set up a web site (www.mydomain.co.za), which I can access directly or via the ftp protocol.
I have created a sub directory off the root where I intend to publish the files created by the publish function. The publish function of the application requires a **Publishing Folder Location** and a **Installation Folder URL** I don't really understand the functional difference between these two locations. If I set the Publishing Location to *ftp://www.mydomain.co.za/MyProductName* and the Installation Folder URL to *http://www.mydomain.co.za/MyProductName*, then the publish process succeeds and when I check on the web server, the files have been published successfully it would seem. A further *Application Files/MyProductName* subdiectory with the version number information appended was created where all the output was placed.

My next step is to then grab the URL of the setup.exe file and to run it from a browser. This downloads the setup.exe file to my downloads folder which I then try to run but I get an error

> Deployment and application do not have matching security zones.>

I have seen this come up in other threads but These threads don't seem to relate directly to what I am trying to do. These threads make mention of using Internet Explorer to achieve some degree of success, but all the browser did was to download the file.

I have also noted with interest that a web page is created in the root with a button that prompts the user to install the application. This does not work either.

Does anyone know of an article that I can read on this subject which is more helpful or if anyone can offer more insights into this I would be very grateful.